# How to print the title in \scshape and \bfseries in this amsart document?

Tags: titles, amsart

I've defined `\newcommand{\Title}{My Article title}` after `\documentclass{amsart}`. I want to use it inside the `\title{}` in the document. But the problem is in this way the `\Title` is not getting printed in `\scshape\bfseries` though this is the default output for `amsart` title.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\Title}{My Title will be here}


\begin{document}
\title{\Title}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see the title is not in `\scshape`.

**Note.** If I directly use `\title{My Title will be here}` then everything works fine. But then I cannot use `\Title` cmd elsewhere in the document.
Can anyone point out why is this happening?

Comment: it is not \scshape, the class does a complicated uppercasing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay. But in any case `\title{\Title}` should produce that uppercase output. Isn't it? I just need to use `\Title` in the document other than `\title{}` so I need it to define in `\Title` newcommand.

Comment: sure, they could simply use (with a current LaTeX) `\MakeUppercase`. Complain to the maintainer of the class, the address is in the class file. As a workaround you can use `\ExpandArgs{o}\title{\Title}`.

Comment: Thanks it works but now how can I give `\ShortTitle` I am trying `\ExpandArgs{o}\title[\ShortTitle]{\Title}` this didn't work.

Comment: The title (and running heads) in `amsart` are not in small caps, but in full caps, for a very practical reason: authors, although it's recommended that they not do so, often include math in titles, and normal-sized math looks stupid embedded in a small caps context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the title in boldface small caps, you can do

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\newcommand{\Title}{My Title will be here}

\begin{document}

\title{\scshape\Title}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Why the change in fonts? Because there is no boldface small caps font in the Computer Modern family (and neither in Latin Modern, if you try).

Boldface is automatically supplied.

[image]

If you just want small caps, you can keep Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\Title}{My Title will be here}

\begin{document}

\title{\mdseries\scshape\Title}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]